# MVC call variable javascript in razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following javascript code:

```
   function myFunctionInJs (){
        var tbody = '';
        $.each(dataArray, function (index, item) {
            tbody += '<tr>
            <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new {Id = item.Id})">View</a>
            </td>
            </tr>';
        });
        $('#myTable').html(tbody);
    }
```

I want to assign `Id = item.Id`
But I do not know how.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible - at least not in the manner you're attempting. JS runs on the client *long* after the C# has completed execution on the server. If you want to send a JS value to C#, the most effective way would be to make an AJAX request

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that won't work

Comment: You can try, `function myFunctionInJs() {
 var url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new {Id = -1})'
  var tbody = '';
 $.each(dataArray, function (index, item) {
  tbody += '<tr><td><a href="' + url.replace(-1, item.Id) + '">View</a></td></tr>';
 });
 $('#myTable').html(tbody);
}`